# How to load layout of custom action in customer account controller

Tags: magento-1.9, layout, customer, customer-account, phtml

I created new action in customer account controller

```
app/code/core/Mage/Customer/controllers/AccountController.php

public function createotpAction()
    {
         $this->loadLayout();
          $this->renderLayout();
    }
```

define layout

```
app/design/frontend/default/default/layout/local.xml
< ?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
<customer_account_createotp>
    <reference name="content">
            <block type="core/template" name="customer_form_otp" template="customer/form/otp.phtml">
        </reference>
</customer_account_createotp>
</layout>
```

define content with phtml

```
app/design/frontend/base/default/template/customer/form/otp.phtml
<?php
    echo 'hello';
?>
```

when i enter url

```
magento/customer/account/createotp/
```

in display theme page with blank content
[image]

can anyone help me to solve this issue 
Thanks in advance for help

Comment: Is it echo'ing from that controller action?

Comment: @MagePsycho in phtml file

Comment: Try to echo in createotpAction() method of your controller I mean.

Comment: @MagePsycho I already tried, if i echo without  loadLayout & renderLayout function it print string on blank screen which is ok, issue is with loading lauout

Comment: Try to enable the developer mode to check if there is any errors logged

Comment: Determine what layout handles are in fact being created. You can use this extension from alan storm for this. https://github.com/astorm/LayoutViewer although it is superseded by commerce bug, it still works standalone.

Comment: Did you clean the layout cache?